# English texts lexicon comparison

Tags: algorithm, statistics, lexicon

Let's imagine, we can build a statistics table, how much each word is used in some English text or book. We can gather statistics for each text/book in library.
What is the simplest way to compare these statistics with each other? How can we find group/cluster of texts with very statistically similar lexicon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'd need to normalize the lexicon (i.e ensure that both lexicons have the *same* vocabulary).

Then you could use a similarity metric like the [Hellenger distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellinger_distance) or the [cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) to compare the two lexicons.

It may also be a good idea to look into machine learning packages such as [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/).

[This book](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cmbishop/prml/) is an excellent source for machine learning and you may find it useful.

Comment: I've taken a brief look through the book, but I didn't find it focused on lexical algorithms. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by seeing what Lucene (http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html ) had to offer. After that you will need to use a machine learning method and look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider Kullback Leibler distance.  For reference, see page 18 of Cover and Thomas:

[Chapter 2, Cover and Thomas](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~vh/courses/LexicalSemantics/Association/Cover&Thomas-Ch2.pdf)